# How to get value from resizable JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resizable, getvalue

I have a JTable 4x4 with default values. User can change JTable size. After changing size to eg. 6x6, default values are cleared and user can type its own. How to get them to some Integer table? I was trying to use getValueAt() and setValueAt() from my model class but JTable fields were always cleared after clicking at some other cell.

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

int size;
private String[] columnNames = { "Stan 1", "Stan 2", "Stan 3", "Stan 4" };

private Object[][] defaultValues = new Object[][] {
        { "5", "15", "10", "0"},
        { "10", "10", "-20", "30"},
        { "40", "0", "50", "-30"},
        { "60", "0", "20", "-10"}};

private Object[][] newData = null;

public MyTableModel(int x) {
    size = x;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    if(columnIndex == 0) return null;
    else return "Stan " + Integer.toString(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return Integer.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if(size == 4)
        return defaultValues[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    else {
        newData = new Object[size][size];
        return newData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if(size == 4)
        defaultValues[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;
    else
        newData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;

    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve] so we can run and test your code ourselves. This should be a small program, small enough to post on this site as code-formatted text, should compile, run and show us your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a custom TableModel or to override the getValueAt(...) and setValueAt(...) method.

If you want to change the data in the `DefaultTableModel` you can just use the `setDataVector(...)` method.